# how to make a screen saver preview in Delphi?

Tags: delphi, screensaver

I want my screensaver appears in the screensaver preview box?

Answer (score 10):

When you make a screen saver you need to support a command line argument (/p [HWND]) that will tell you in which windows to show your screen saver. The command line will be pass to you thru the screen saver control panel. [here is a link to the full spec](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/182383).

Comment: Missing from the page you link to (unless I overlooked) is that you should rename the executable to the ".scr" file extension and store it under the "%SYSTEMROOT%\SYSTEM32" folder

Comment: Yes, that's how windows find screen savers.

Answer (score 0):

You can start the screen saver, get it's window handle then change it's parent to your forms handle or panel's handle or wherever you want it.