# Create a screensaver preview in Delphi

Tags: delphi, preview, screensaver

I've created a screen saver in Delphi 10 Lite, using diffrent descriptions about this question, available on the web. Now, the screen saver works well, one thing is missing: a good working preview on the Screen Saver Settings dialog box. How can it be created? I've read this description: [how to make a screen saver preview in Delphi?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/903180/how-to-make-a-screen-saver-preview-in-delphi)
but I'd like something more specific, maybe with an example. I'm using Windows 7 Ultimate SP1.
Thanks.

Comment: How your screen saver implemented, exactly?

Comment: What is unclear about the instructions on that other question? You have to implement the `/p` command-line argument to accept an `HWND` as input. If provided, you simply render your screensaver normally using that `HWND` as the parent window for your screensaver's UI, otherwise you create your own full-screen `HWND` as the parent window instead.

Comment: There's no such thing as Delphi 10 Lite. What version of Delphi are you really using?

Answer (score 5):

The Embarcadero site, provides a fully functional screen saver sample, which includes the   normal execution (run), preview, password setting and so on. Try this article [`Random Images Screen Saver - a complete screen saver example`](http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/26652), the source code can be downloaded from [here](http://cc.embarcadero.com/Item/15504).

Comment: I don't know what's happening, but I can't properly open the source code: difrent error messages appears. Now I will take a look to the website to see if I can find something useful. Thank you, anyway.

Comment: @LaszloBalazs - I confirm. As usual, the Embarcadero site is broken (The connection has timed out).

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I did in [my little scrub screen saver test](http://www.tek-tips.com/faqs.cfm?fid=6914) (done to see how one works more than it be polished):

WinHandle is the window id passed during the /P switch.  I rigged things (the screen saver just puts up a defined text in different colors with a defined delay between them) for the screen saver to act on a window handle so I didn't have to duplicate the screen saver code itself.  SS_Init initializes things for the screen saver, SS_Start does one step of it, SS_End wraps things up.

```
if program_state = Preview then  // code before indicates /P was passed
  begin
    { spindle off messages until window is visible }
    while not IsWindowVisible(WinHandle) do
      Application.ProcessMessages;
    { initialize and do screen saver draw }
    start_time := WinMSSinceStart; // timeGetTime
    SS_Init(WinHandle);
    while IsWindowVisible(Winhandle) do
      begin
        if (WinMSSinceStart - Start_Time) >= config_rec.Delay then
          begin
             SS_Start(WinHandle);
             start_time := WinMSSinceStart;
          end;
        Application.ProcessMessages;
        sleep(10);
      end;
    SS_End(Winhandle);
end;
```

Here's how you set up the TCanvas to draw on the window handle that is passed (this is in SS_Init (but not the whole thing).  MyCanvas is a property I have defined in line with this code:

```
  { get window dimensions and set up TCanvas }
  GetClientRect(WinHandle, WinRect);
  MyCanvas := TCanvas.Create;
  MyCanvas.Handle := GetDC(Winhandle);
```

Then when you're done (this is my whole SS_End function):

```
  ReleaseDC(WinHandle, MyCanvas.Handle);
  MyCanvas.Free;
```

Hope that helps out.

Comment: Thank you, I will take a look and will come back.